# How do I update just the "nativescript-vue" package in my project?

Tags: nativescript, upgrade, nativescript-vue

I'm new to Nativescript and Mobile app development in general. How do I update just the "nativescript-vue" package in my project? My project has nativescript-vue version 2.4.0, but I'm trying to update to version 2.6.1.

Here is a snippet from the packson.json in my project.

```
"@nativescript/theme": "~2.2.1",
"nativescript-vue": "~2.4.0",
"tns-core-modules": "~6.3.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Either change in package.json to `"nativescript-vue": "~2.6.1",` and run npm install or simply run `npm update nativescript-vue`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out how to do it.

From the terminal I ran the following command...
npm i nativescript-vue@2.6.1

You could open the Project in vscode and run the command from the terminal there too.

To get the latest version run
npm i nativescript-vue@latest